# In eevee,I want to connect transparent bsdf and emission to a mix shader and paint by factor, but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, transparency, shader-nodes, toon-shading

I'm trying to create transparency with toon shader, but I can't paint by factor, even though I can adjust the transparency.
When I connect the texture to the factor, I can paint the image as I intended.

[image]

This is the factor.

[image]

However, when I connect "shader to RGB" to the factor, for some reason everything becomes transparent.

[image]

This is the factor.

[image]

I want to render using alpha hashed, so please help me with the solution using alpha hashed.
If anyone knows the solution or the cause, please let me know.

The environment is eevee, SSR in Scene is checked, and blend mode is alpha hashed.

I'm Japanese and my English is hard to read, but I hope you can help me.;)

Answer (score 1):

This is not Shader to RGB problem. If you do this:
[image]

as you did, you are basically, making whole cube white, then you use color ramp and make white white again... you are basically coloring whole cube in white color and white color will give whole surface Fac (for example) 1 so your whole cube is transparent... If you want to make your cube checked as you had it, you need to put texture with color ramp in Fac.

If you want to color it somehow, then you need to combine color in one of Shader inputs in Mix Shader and Fac needs to be left for that checker texture...

If this didn't asnwer your question then I don't know what else you needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I don't want to paint with a checkered pattern, I want to make the shadows transparent. I apologize for the confusion.
So I'm using diffuse bsdf to get the shadow information, then converting it to RGB and connecting the values as Fac.
But the whole cube is transparent, not just the shadows, and I want to know why and how to fix it.

If I have misunderstood the content due to my lack of reading comprehension, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

For any transparency to function in Eevee, you need to set the material's Blender options to anything else than opaque. In your specific case, Alpha Blender seem to be the only one working with that node setup:

[image: demo picture]

Also, maybe a color ramp isn't the best option if all you need is "cutting off" the shadow with pure black/white. A match node in `Greater Than` mode will do, and is easier to control.